# change the color of font awesome's exclamation triangle icon

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have to use font awesome's exclamation triangle icon but I need to have the exclamation's mark in Red color and triangle's background in white.
When I change the color of the icon to Red, it does the opposite. Can someone help me with this?

```
<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-3x" style = "color:#C00000"></i>
```

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: post the code in jsfiddle or paste it here so that we can help

Comment: No you cannot. You need to create your own vector icon.

Comment: How about using a real warning sign ⚠ instead of FontAwesome.

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada How to create my own vector icon..any links for that.

Comment: @ChankiAhuja Here are some of them: https://fonticons.com/ , http://fontello.com/ , http://fontastic.me/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, the triangle is not in the FontAwesome collection, but if you doesn't matter if will be an square instead of a triangle, you can stack icons:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x" style="color: white;"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-exclamation fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" style="color:red;"></i>
</span>
```

See it working: http://jsfiddle.net/ao486t04/

Comment: Thanks Marcos for the example. But I really needed the triangle and it isn't there in FontAwesome collection. Well I used "fa-inverse" to invert the colors and that worked.

Comment: Ok , sorry for I can't help you better. FontAwesome is awesome, but I think that a triangle is a neccesary icon in the collection. Maybe we can suggest it.

Comment: Yellow triangle, black exclamation... using the triangle icon as 'background': http://jsfiddle.net/xojtv3Ld/

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use the original exclamation triangle and stack it.

```css
body {
  background:red;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="fa-stack fa-sm">
  <i class="fa fa-exclamation fa-stack-2x fa-inverse" style="font-size:1.5em; padding-top:.2em"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-stack-2x" style="color:blue;"></i>
</span>

<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-exclamation fa-stack-2x fa-inverse" style="font-size:1.5em; padding-top:.2em"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-stack-2x" style="color:blue;"></i>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your vector icon in illustrator or corel draw. Or open your png of icon in  photoshop and add red color with buket on the triangle area.. hope this hack helps